# Error during installation ROracle on macOS M1

Tags: r, macos, roracle

I can't install **ROracle** on **MacBook Air M2** with **MacOS Ventura 13.4.1** and **R** from **brew**.

## Preconditions

- MacBook Air M2
- MacOS Ventura 13.4.1
- R from brew

```
> Sys.info()                                                                                                
sysname "Darwin" 
release "22.5.0" 
version "Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Thu Jun  8 22:21:34 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.3~7/RELEASE_ARM64_T8112"                                                                                                nodename "HostName.local"                                                                                                 machine "arm64"                                                                                                  login "UserName" 
user "UserName" 
effective_user "UserName"
```

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin22.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.4.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openblas/0.3.23/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.23.dylib 
LAPACK: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.3.1/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] pl_PL.UTF-8/pl_PL.UTF-8/pl_PL.UTF-8/C/pl_PL.UTF-8/pl_PL.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/Warsaw
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1
```

`install.packages("DBI")`

I'm installing ROracle according:
[https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL]

So, I've installed Oracle Instant Client Version 12.2.0.1.0

- Basic Package
- SDK Package
- SQL*Plus Package
  from site
  https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html

With environment

```
ORACLE_HOME="/Users/UserName/instantclient_12_2"
export ORACLE_HOME
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH
export PATH
```

`sqlplus` works properly.

## Installing

When I am installing ROracle:

`R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/Users/UserName/instantclient_12_2 --with-oci-inc=/Users/UserName/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include' ~/Downloads/ROracle_1.3-1.1.tar.gz`

## Result

I get the result:

```
* installing to library ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘ROracle’ ...
** pakiet ‘ROracle’ został pomyślnie rozpakowany oraz sumy MD5 zostały sprawdzone
** using staged installation
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX13.3.sdk’
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.3.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/Users/UserName/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
rodbi.c:2432:53: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
        sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
rodbi.c:2469:53: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
        sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
rodbi.c:2816:55: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
          sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
rodbi.c:2861:55: warning: format specifies type 'long long' but the argument has type 'sb8' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
          sprintf(err_buf, RODBI_ERR_BIND_VAL_TOOBIG, bndsz);
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.3.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/Users/UserName/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c rooci.c -o rooci.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.3.1/lib/R/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -o ROracle.so rodbi.o rooci.o -L/Users/UserName/instantclient_12_2 -lclntsh -Wl,-rpath,/Users/UserName/instantclient_12_2 -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.3.1/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/UserName/instantclient_12_2/libclntsh.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
installing to /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/00LOCK-ROracle/00new/ROracle/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
```

## Error

...and it ends up with an error:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object  '/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/00LOCK-ROracle/00new/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
  dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/00LOCK-ROracle/00new/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_OCIArrayDescriptorAlloc'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

No answer to a similar earlier question fixes this error:

- [Installing ROracle (and the Oracle Instant Client?) on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821311/installing-roracle-and-the-oracle-instant-client-on-macos)
- [ROracle not loading Instantclient library on MacOS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869888/roracle-not-loading-instantclient-library-on-macos-high-sierra?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C83.3091)
- [Install ROracle in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313333/install-roracle-in-mac/49518354?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C24.1321#49518354)

Comment: This could be a delicate matter of getting correct versions and architectures in alignment.  Start by using the latest ROracle driver from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html (The CRAN one is out of date for CRAN reasons).   Then get a much more recent Instant Client, e.g. 19.8.  You'll need to use an x86 version of R since Instant Client is only x86.  You will likely need to get an older version of R - see the ROracle INSTALL file in the bundle.  (Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260737/4799035)

Comment: @ChristopherJones, thank you for help. The package installed correctly when I used the older version of R (3.5.x) as you advised.

Comment: Keep an eye on oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html for when we release an updated ROracle driver.